# linking JSON to html for using particles.js does not work

Tags: html, css, json, particles, particles.js

I have downloaded the JSON library configuaration from this website : https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/#default. I am new to JSON and therefore I dont understand what has gone wrong. When I compile only a blue screen pops up on my browser, which means that only css plays. Could someone please help me understand what has gone wrong? I am sorry for the long post, but I honestly dont know how else to fit it so that I can give a clear picture of what I am doing.

This is my HTML file called `particles.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="particles.js"></script>
<link href="particles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body id="particles-js">

   <script type="text/javascript">
    particlesJS("particles-js",<strong>particlesjs-config.json</strong>);
  </script>

 </body>

</html>
```

This is my CSS file called `particles.css`

```
body{
    background: cornflowerblue;
   }
```

And this is the JSON configuration I downloaded. The file is called `particlesjs-config.json`

```
    {
"particles": {
  "number": {
    "value": 80,
    "density": {
      "enable": true,
      "value_area": 800
    }
  },
  "color": {
    "value": "#ffffff"
  },
  "shape": {
    "type": "circle",
    "stroke": {
      "width": 0,
      "color": "#000000"
   },
    "polygon": {
      "nb_sides": 5
    },
    "image": {
      "src": "img/github.svg",
      "width": 100,
      "height": 100
    }
  },
  "opacity": {
    "value": 0.5,
  "random": false,
  "anim": {
    "enable": false,
    "speed": 1,
    "opacity_min": 0.1,
    "sync": false
  }
},
"size": {
  "value": 3,
  "random": true,
  "anim": {
    "enable": false,
    "speed": 40,
    "size_min": 0.1,
    "sync": false
  }
},
"line_linked": {
  "enable": true,
  "distance": 150,
  "color": "#ffffff",
  "opacity": 0.4,
  "width": 1
},
"move": {
  "enable": true,
  "speed": 6,
  "direction": "none",
  "random": false,
  "straight": false,
  "out_mode": "out",
  "bounce": false,
  "attract": {
    "enable": false,
    "rotateX": 600,
    "rotateY": 1200
    }
  }
},
 "interactivity": {
  "detect_on": "canvas",
  "events": {
    "onhover": {
      "enable": true,
    "mode": "repulse"
  },
  "onclick": {
    "enable": true,
    "mode": "push"
  },
  "resize": true
},
"modes": {
  "grab": {
    "distance": 400,
    "line_linked": {
      "opacity": 1
    }
  },
  "bubble": {
    "distance": 400,
    "size": 40,
    "duration": 2,
    "opacity": 8,
    "speed": 3
  },
  "repulse": {
    "distance": 200,
    "duration": 0.4
  },
  "push": {
    "particles_nb": 4
  },
  "remove": {
    "particles_nb": 2
  }
  }
},
  "retina_detect": true
}
```

Comment: do you have an extra } on the 4th last line?

Comment: @FiringSquadWitness no I think its nor extra. I downloaded the configuration so didnt really do anything on the JSON file

Comment: @JordanQuartermain thanks a lot for the comment but that is also not working. Console shows : failed to load resource assets/particles.json

Comment: Where is your JSON file located? Can you get a screenshot of your console too?

Comment: @JordanQuartermain the JSON file is located in the same folder where the particles.html file is. Is this correct? 
also, what exactly do u want me to screenshot from the console? I havent used it so far. Maybe thats where the problem lies?

Answer (score 0):

See this page 
https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js

It looks like you're loading the JSON file incorrectly. Should be similar to this

```
<script>
  particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'particles.json', function(){
    console.log('particles.json loaded...do your thing!');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: tried that as well and also didnt work...do u have any ide what else could be wrong?